# What is the command in monero cli to send some coins to an address or multiple addresses at once?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-fees, transactions

What is the cli command to send some coins to 1 address and the command to send to multiple addresses by paying a fee once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transfer should do it

> transfer [< priority>] [< ring_size>] < address> < amount> [< payment_id>] - Transfer < amount> to < address>. < priority> is the priority of the transaction. The higher the priority, the higher the fee of the transaction. Valid values in priority order (from lowest to highest) are: unimportant, normal, elevated, priority. If omitted, the default value (see the command "set priority") is used. < ring_size> is the number of inputs to include for untraceability. Multiple payments can be made at once by adding < address_2> < amount_2> etcetera (before the payment ID, if it's included)

you can transfer to multiple addresses but you can transfer using only one payment_id per transaction ie:

```
transfer <address_1> <amount_1> <address_2> <amount_2> <address_3> <amount_3> <payment_id>
```

Comment: how to do this is the gui?

Comment: @duckx The GUI does not currently support sending to multiple destinations in a single tx.

Comment: if i was create a web gui using php, how can i expose these cli commands to my php script?